# Notes Application not able to open after upgrading to MacOs Sierra

Tags: macos

I have Macbook Pro 15" Retina display. I recently upgraded to macOS Sierra from El Capitan.  After upgrading, I am no longer able to open my Notes application.

I have important data on Notes; how can i recover or can fix this issue ?

---

Please check it out and please help me what should i do.
Thanks

Comment: how to update it ? can't able to find notes on apple apps store.

Answer (score 3):

I had an old mail account which doesn't work any more, but in the `System Preferences -> Internet Accounts` preference pane in the `Use With` list Notes were switched on for this account. After I turned it off I was able to launch Notes.

Answer (score 2):

You have an mail account that is not working because of wrong password or something like that. You have to delete this account in Accounts from Mail menu. I had the same problem.

Comment: The question is about Notes, *not* Mail.

Comment: I had the same problem 5 minutes ago with Notes. I deleted the wrong mail account and now Notes is working

Comment: before that, I click the option "Activate the account "In my Mac" in Preferences from Notes menu. I am translating to English because I have Spanish version. I'm sorry, if you read any differences.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I went into System Preferences/iCloud and turned off Notes and turned it back on. I was then able to use the Notes app with no problem.

Comment: I tried it, and still it's crashing :(